# Suitable widget for differentiating parent and child categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am displaying categories through a widget in my wordpress website, but what i want to do is to show just the parent categories, and child categories on dropdown with each. Can anyone suggest me a suitable widget for that, so that all of my categories can easily be adjusted and differentiated..

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/collapsing-categories/screenshots/

Comment: i tried this but its not displaying any category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best one for this problem is using "jQuery Categories List widget". it easily seperates parent and child categories.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter/

You'll have to look at the support and figure out the shortcode combination to achieve what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: i actually want to show and hide subcategories in sidebar